# Why I see code coverage for apex class and for some I cannot

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app

When I go to Setup -> Apex Classes, I could see code coverage percentage for some of the classes and for some I cannot. Do you know what is the reason behind this? Is there some specific setting I am missing ?

Comment: can you elaborate this with an example along with some screenshots

Comment: Thank you, that was my bad. Apparantly, the class page was too long and I was not able to see to the end of it, where the code coverage was. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Classes annotated with @isTest never have coverage, and do not count against your code coverage. Classes that have been modified since the last time your tests have run, or after clearing test data, will show 0% until you run the tests again.

Comment: Thank you, that was my bad. Apparantly, the class page was too long and I was not able to see to the end of it, where the code coverage was. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code coverage for your "apex class" not for "testclass" you have written.

Please Go to setup-->apex classes

check below image. Here you can see the code coverage of your test class

[image]

If it shows 0% coverage means you have to write "test class" for that if you are moving your changes from sandbox to production

Go to developer console,click on test-->RunAll. It gives your org code coverage

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you all, that was my bad. Apparantly, the class page was too long and I was not able to see to the end of it, where the code coverage was. Thank you again!